# Bootstrap div put up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I learn Bootstrap but I have same problem.

Show my pictures, I have container div and col 2 and col 3 but I want take top.

https://hizliresim.com/ZVbL0g

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 p0 red">col2</div>
            <div class=" col-md-offset-8 col-md-2  red">col3</div>
            </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "take top"??

Comment: Andrew i want col 2 and col 3 div "put up" sorry my english.

Comment: check the height of element. Set it to auto. And check if parent container is given auto height.

Comment: Please Can You Share more Info And Coding

Comment: Post your code here on StackOverflow or in a jsfiddle NOT in a image.

Answer (score 0):

Try THis One

```
 <div class="container" style="background:red;">
        <div class="row" style="background:pink;">
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 p0 red">col2</div>
                <div class=" col-md-offset-8 col-md-2  red">col3</div>
                </div>

        <div class="container" >


        </div>
    </diV>
```

Comment: Can You Upload Your Code To Fiddler